# Request header field X-Mime-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, response-headers, same-origin-policy

Okay, I've been struggling a few hours now with this stupid problem.

We've got a blog (WordPress), and a website (2 different sites). We show the blog on our website via a reversed proxy.

Now we have in our WordPress blog article an upload field for an image. When we go to our blog, and upload an image it works fine. But when we go to the reversed proxy and try to upload an image, we get the following error:

```
Failed to load https://ourblog.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=ufb_file_upload_action&file_uploader_nonce=42d24cf604&allowedExtensions%5B0%5D=jpg&allowedExtensions%5B1%5D=jpeg&allowedExtensions%5B2%5D=png&sizeLimit=8000000&element_id=9786&qqfile=fileName.jpg: Request header field X-Mime-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Now I've tried to add this in my functions.php (theme):

```
add_action( 'init', 'handle_preflight' );
function handle_preflight() {
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: https://www.ourwebsite.com');
    header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: X-HTTP-Method-Override, Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept, Authorization");
    header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET, POST, PUT');
}
```

But that doesn't help. How can I fix this error?

The plug-in for the form upload is [this one](https://accesspressthemes.com/wordpress-plugins/ultimate-form-builder/)

Comment: try to use http instead of https.